# What paramilitary group was Nikola Jorgić in?

Tags: military, yugoslavia, serbia, bosnian-war

> "Nikola Jorgić (1946 – 8 June 2014) was a Bosnian Serb from the Doboj region who was a soldier of a paramilitary group located in his native area.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Jorgi%C4%87) On 26 September 1997, he was convicted of genocide in Germany. This was the first conviction won against participants in the Bosnian Genocide. Jorgić was sentenced to four terms of life imprisonment for his involvement in the Bosnian genocide." - From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Jorgi%C4%87).

The Wikipedia article doesn't specifically state which paramilitary group Nikola Jorgić was in, though it states that said paramilitary group was in the Doboj region. Does anyone know which paramilitary group he was in specifically? Or is this information unknown?

Answer (score 2):

It was simply called "Jorgina grupa" or Jorga's group in English. You can find it [here](https://www.justice-report.com/en/articles/wheels-of-justice-grind-slowly-in-doboj), [here](https://www.slobodnaevropa.org/a/posmrtni_ostaci_civila_iz_grapske_jos_nisu_pronadjeni/24578531.html) and [here](https://nap.ba/news/46726)